# Keyup (or down) double-firing not single-firing

Tags: javascript

When the button is clicked it shows on the screen the array being captured. Then with each hit of the *enter* button, each element should display in the console.

With *keyup* it is triggering twice. With *keydown* it fires once as desired, but then twice with each subsequent press of the *enter* button.

The code looks correct. I can't see where this would be coming from. There are quite a few questions related to this problem, but not one answer resolved the issue. Any ideas?

```js
const myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

const myFunction = function(v) {
  document.querySelector('.show').innerHTML = v;
  document.body.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13 && v.length > 0) {
      console.log(v.pop());
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<body class="container">
  <p class='show'></p>
  <button class="myBtn" onclick="myFunction(myArray)">Click</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Preventing default action on Enter seems to solve the problem.

```js
const myArray = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

const myFunction = function(v) {
  document.querySelector('.show').innerHTML = v;
  document.body.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13 && v.length > 0) {     
      console.log(v.pop());
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<body class="container">
  <p class='show'></p>
  <button class="myBtn" onclick="myFunction(myArray)">Click</button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're adding a new EventListener each `click`

Try removing the `keydown` event listener from the click function

```
    window.onload = function () {
document.body.addEventListener('keydown', function(e){
                if ( e.keyCode == 13 && myArray.length > 0) {
                    console.log(myArray.pop());                                  
                }
            });

}

const myFunction = function(v) {
  document.querySelector('.show').innerHTML = v;
  // the keyup is taken care of elsewhere
}
```